# What can I do if a builder ignores me while I try to have them fix something that is under warranty?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I am a US citizen living in the US. I own a condo, which has a builder's warranty on it. I have been attempting to contact the builder to fix an issue with my roof/ceiling that is covered on the active (ie not expired) warranty, but have not received a response for a few weeks. If they simply continue to ignore me, what can I do? What happens if the problem gets worse and worse? Is suing the builder the only option? I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can politely request over the phone that he fix it. You can politely request by letter that he fix it. You can hire an attorney to firmly request by letter that he fix it. You can sue him to get the courts to order him to fix it. You can also decide to fix it and forget the warranty. One thing that you can't do is let the physical situation get worse to the point of disaster and hope to recover the even greater damages that would result. If he is ignoring your letters, then get a lawyer.

Comment: If I fix it myself (via my own contractor) can I have the builder reimburse me via the warranty? Or once I fix it myself its set in stone that its my money only?

Comment: You probably have zero chance of a reimbursement if you opt for DIY without having exhausted the prior remedies such as lawyer and lawsuit. However, if the lawyer's first letter is not successful and if it turns out that the problem is that the guy is swamped, he may be amenable to a DIY compromise that could be advantageous to you, but again, this involves the lawyer.